# How to print $ using String Interpolation

Tags: scala

I have just started learning scala .I want to print $ using String Interpolation

```
def main(args:Array[String]){
println("Enter the string")
val inputString:String=readLine()
val inputAsDouble:Double=inputString.toDouble
printf(f" You owe '${inputAsDouble}%.1f3 ")
}
```

Input is 2.7255 I get output as .You owe 2.73 while i want it as You owe $2.73
any pointers will be of a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just double it

```
printf(f" You owe $$${inputAsDouble}%.1f3 ")
```

Result:

```
16/06/02 10:16:04: You owe $2,73
```

Comment: this is a triple though